# Destructuring Objects as Function Parameters With Flow Types

Tags: javascript, types, ecmascript-6, flowtype, static-typing

How to destructure parameters of a function while still keeping Flow type anotation for new (destructured) values?

Example:

```
type Car = {
  model: string,
  maxSpeed: number
}

function processCar({ model, maxSpeed }: Car) {
  // model should be anotated as string 
  // and maxSpeed as number here but that is not the case
}
```

Is there any syntax to specify those missing types manually? They do not seems to be inferred automatically (at pressent, is there Flow proposal for that?).

Comment: They are inferred. See this [example](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwghgJygXigbwFBSgWwPYAmEANgFxQDOwCAlgHYDmANFrnAB4DKkEB5dAVxwAjCAgwBfDBgBmAugGNgNPHShgEeBRAoV4CABRpchEkzZceBKBPL6AlOlYLVVSihNFiUAPRQArADczq7AUGqoOBzcELwAdBRgxDTABgDkafbBEkA).